# TensorFlow - Slicing tensor results in: ValueError: Shape (16491,) must have rank 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to slice tensor to get specific tensor by list of index, for example:

```
word_weight   = tf.get_variable("word_weight", [20])
a= word_weight[ [1,6,5] ]
```

*(I want to get `word_weight[1], word_weight[6], word_weight[5]`)*

But I get the following error when I run the code:

```
ValueError: Shape (16491,) must have rank 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, evaluate the tensor first. Then, you can index them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

word_weight = tf.get_variable("word_weight", [20])

with tf.Session() as sess:   
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    x = sess.run(word_weight)
    print(x[[1,6,5]])
    # Or evaluete like this
    print(sess.run([word_weight[1],word_weight[6],word_weight[5]]))
```

This outputs:

```
[ 1.61491954  0.66727936 -0.73491937]
```

Comment: Can I evaluate the tensor after indexing  them? i.e. X= word_weight[ [1,6,5] ], y=sess.run(X)

Comment: @NilsCao This may work:  x = sess.run([word_weight[1],word_weight[6],word_weight[5]])
    print(x). I added in the answer.

Comment: Can x=sess.run(word_weight[[1,6,5]]) work too?  I'm sorry that I'm not near the computer now.

Comment: @NilsCao, sess.run(word_weight[[1,6,5]]) ooes not work.

Comment: That is so wired. Thank you so much. I'm doing the nerural network algorithm. I put the tensor variable definition and propagate algorithm in the init function of a class and evaluate the tensor after creating the object of the class. It seems I should not put the propagate algorithm in the init function of class so that I can fix my question.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Do you know why `sess.run(word_weight[[1,6,5]])` does not work?